# Ansible: copy with dynamic reference to username

Tags: ansible

Really new to Ansible (v2.5.2) and in a task defined I want to dynamically refer to the `ansible_user` defined in the hosts file. So when there are many user names, the playbook does not break.

The host inventory file looks similar to:

```
[masters]
master ansible_host=00.00.00.000 ansible_user=fancy-admin
```

And the task looks like:

```
- name: example copying file with owner and permissions
  become: yes
  copy:
    src: /etc/myfiles/foo.conf
    dest: /home/<ansible_user>/foo.conf
    remote_src: yes
    owner: <ansible_user>
    mode: 0644
```

So, the `ansible_user` name is used to define the destination directory and to set the ownership. Also open for alternative methods to define the user's home directory (while using the `become=yes` setting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
  - name: example copying file with owner and permissions
      become: yes
      copy:
        src: /etc/myfiles/foo.conf
        dest: "/home/{{ ansible_user }}/foo.conf"
        remote_src: yes
        owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
        mode: 0644
```